# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns exception on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to display an image using the following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
       Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                               selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Log.wtf("M3K", "Above decode");
            Bitmap logoBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            Log.wtf("M3K", "Below decode");

            //Display image on layout
            Log.wtf("M3K", "Above display");
            logo.setImageBitmap(logoBMP);
            Log.wtf("M3K", "Below display");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is on `Bitmap logoBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);` where on Android 4.4 (tested on my Nexus 7) it will return a file not found exception, with the reason being **EACCES (Permission denied)**. This works perfectly on an ASUS Transformer Infinity running 4.2 and worked perfectly on my Nexus 7 running 4.3. Does anyone know what has to change for KitKat compatibility?

Note: I get the image URI through the following code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Comment: permission denied means, try to give WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to put the following in your manifestfile:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't believe the solution was so simple.